# undefined method `user_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8da82da248>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am error in the 2nd line of the code here, I have a column user_id in the Estate table. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
myestate = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company)
@managements = User.where(:id => myestate.user_id)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`where` is returning an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object. Because `where(:mgmt => current_user.company)` could return 0, 1, or Many records, you have to tell the query what you'd like from it.

Try:

```
myestate = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company).first
@managements = User.where(:id => myestate.user_id)
```

Getting familiar with AREL and how it works is highly recommended. You can find great info on the [github page](https://github.com/rails/arel) or the [Active Record Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: oh !!! i get it. so its like there are many elements in myestate and :id => myestate.user_id is having trouble in comparing which id to which user_id, so what can i do find User for each of the estate ?

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar you're right. To get a good answer, ask that as another question on Stackoverflow. Explaining in the comments will be cumbersome.